# node js - detect and prevent duplicate processes

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a situation where I only want one instance of my application running at one time, how would I detect and prevent a codebase being ran twice?

Currently, my code is initiated from the command line and I intend when the application is running and a command has been given, a message will be sent to the pre-existing instance

Comment: Create a lock file on startup and check if it exists

Comment: You need to remove the file when the application quits as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, one way to stop the same process from getting created is to create a `lock` file. This file usually contains nothing, but you can place whatever you want in it. We will only need to know that the file exists or not.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

// Create the path to the lock file
const lockFile = path.join(__dirname, './lock')
// Test the lock file
const lock = fs.statSync(lockFile)

if (lock.isFile()) {
  // The file already exists, exit the process
  process.exit()
} else {
  // The file does not exist, let's create it
  fs.writeFileSync(lockFile, '')

  // Before the application quits, remove the lock file
  process.on('beforeExit', () => fs.unlinkSync(lockFile))
}
```

The downside to a lock file, is that if your application crashes, the `lock` file will not get removed, and will need to be manually removed.

**Note:** The `process.on()` needs to be in the `else` otherwise the exiting application will possibly remove the file.

Comment: This looks good, but I'd suggest a couple of enhancements a) write the lockfile to OS's temp directory instead of littering the app folder and b) Maintain a lock on the file while process is running so that some other process cannot delete it (the current code uses a create-and-forget approach).

Comment: Also, how about handing `uncaughtException` and `exit`? OP might be invoking `process.exit()` elsewhere..

Comment: Following @Vasan's suggestion, if you open the file to write (instead of just `stat()`ing it) then you will effectively acquire a lock that will expire if your process terminates abnormally.

(Traditionally, one would write the PID of the owning process to the file so that other tools could terminate the process at need.)

Comment: @DavidW Would you do `fs.createWriteStream(path_to_file)`, write pid and just `.end()` and delete the file once terminating?

Comment: @JasonAllan Yes, it's basically that simple.  And `createWriteStream()` failing (can't open file for write) indicates that another process is running.